# How to structure a React app to pass values returned from a child's function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, software-design, mobx

I'm building a react app that I want to seperate into three layers, and am having a little trouble wrapping my head around how they should be structured and in what hierarchy to best support React practices.

The three layers are service (only api calls), business logic, and UI. My goal here is to allow the service and business layers to be reusable and not be tied to specific UI components.

So in my mind, the structure of my program should be UI > (is the parent of) Business logic > (is the parent of) the service layer. However, I'm finding it difficult to see how this approach makes sense in react, so I'm wondering if it's the right idea. My issue is that as I understand it, parents pass down props to children. However, I need my service layer to pass objects to my business logic so it can do it's thing and effeciently hand off to the UI for display.

Here's a trimmed version of my service layer:

```
interface State {
    queues: any
}

@observer
class DeadletterService extends Component<Props, State> {

    @observable deadletterQueue: [];
    @observable queues: [];

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            queues: []
        };

        this.queues = this.getQueues();
        this.deadletterQueue = this.getByQueue("urlSlug");
    }

    // returns all queues as a JSON array
    getQueues(): any {

        let url = "url";

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                return data;
            });
    }

    // given the name of a queue, returns the queue's deadletters as a JSON array
    getByQueue(id: string): any {

        let url = "url/{id}";

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                return data;
            });

        return 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DeadletterLogic testQueues={this.queues}  /> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here's a trimmed version of my logic layer:

```
interface Props {
    testQueues: any;
}

interface State {
    queues: any
}

@observer
class DeadletterLogic extends Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            queues: []
        };
        this.getQueues();
    }

    // here is where the business logic will be done
    getQueues() {
        // in order to gets a list of queues here, a fetch call must be made in the service layer to the MessageQueueAPI
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // when passing from a parent, I'm not sure if this needs to live here or if it can live in getQueues to update when the fetch is finished.
        this.setState({ queues: this.props.testQueues });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.testQueues}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What's the best way to get the values returned from an api call in my service layer to my business layer in React? Because it's an async fetch call, I also need my business layer to update after I actually get data back.

Cheers!

Comment: A couple of directions to look: `Redux`, and also `Redux-Saga`. These are both complex though; I'd stay away if possible. For a more primitive (but not quite as sophisticated) approach, consider React Context.

Comment: if you do not use context or redux, the way to do this is to think of react as a hierarchy/tree of loaded components. values can not be passed up the tree. however you can adjust your thinking by passing values all the way down the tree.  
 if you define a state in a parent component and pass that state down to a child component, then adjusting state in the child component will similarly adjust state in the parent. (shared state). I have used this approach in primitive apps, and it gets irritating fast. Redux is a much more robust / elegant method after initial learning curve.

Comment: You should structure your hierarchy according to the UI components. You can lift the child states up to have logics in the parent and let the parent control the behavior of the children.

Comment: What you're describing is a pattern called Higher Order Component. Create a function that takes a component, applies some logic to it and returns a new component based on the first one that receives data through props.
In terms of hierarchy, from parent to child: Services > Business logic > UI. The UI depends on services and business logic, not the other way around.

Comment: As other people have pointed out, your hierarchy is backwards. Think of your app in terms of blocks that depend on each other. In your case, the UI depends on the business logic because it displays data and controls based on the state of the app. The business logic depends on the service layer because that's where it gets the data. So the structure is Service -> Business Logic -> UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why are you using your service and business layer as components? As you've said

> My goal here is to allow the service and business layers to be
>   reusable and not be tied to specific UI components.

That means that they should not be related to any UI meaning those layers could be used in angular, react-native or any other UI layer implementation.

So you could have api layer (service):

```
class DeadletterService {
    async getQueues(filter) {
        const response = await fetch(...);
        return await response.json();
    }

    // other api calls
}

const service = new DeadletterService();
export default service;
```

As you can see service just request and return data (no state) based on some input (for example filter, id or something else).

Then you have business layer where you fetch data from services, do whatever transformations on data you want and store that data in some kind of state which will be used on the UI layer.

```
import deadLetterService from './deadLetterService';

class DeadletterStore {
    @observable queues = [];

    @action
    async getQueues() {
        const queues = await deadLetterService.getQueues();
        // do some mapping if needed
        this.queues = queues;
    }
}
```

Now you can use that store inside your UI - since you are using MobX you can make use of inject function:

```
@inject('deadLetterStore');
class DeadletterPage extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.deadLetterStore.getQueues();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.deadLetterStore.queues.map((queue) => <span>{queue.name}</span>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Please note that this code is not tested - its just to point out structure design.